# AngularJS ui router mandatory parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Based on the documentation, angularjs ui-router url parameters are by default optional. So is there a way to create mandatory parameters? Like when the parameter is missing or null it will not proceed to the page?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why not 'if (typeof param === 'undefined') and then redirect?

Comment: or before in your template and just not show the link?

Comment: It's not on my view already. Also I can't do it on my controller, is there a way to do it while declaring the states?

Comment: Then I don't know. I think you should not load an init state with url parameters. Just redirect after the init in your init directive or controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UI Routers [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to check if route params are missing.

```
//Example of a single route
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard/:userId',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
  controller: 'DashboardController',
  resolve: function($stateParams, $location){

    //Check if url parameter is missing.
    if ($stateParams.userId === undefined) {
      //Do something such as navigating to a different page.
      $location.path('/somewhere/else');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the scripts are minified. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That is not good. Apologies. Try removing the [] wrapping the resolve function.

Comment: For future reference, instead of removing the [], I did it the way AngularJS wants it to be:

`resolve : ['$stateParams', '$location', function($stateParams, $location){
    //body here
}]`

Comment: resolve is an *object* with *keys and values*.  It should be `resolve: { somekey: function($stateParams, $location){ ... } }`.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer prasents incorrect usage of **resolve** that will fail when code is minified even if annotated. [Look at this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3387#event-1015387626) I've spent a lot of time debugging this, because ui-router@0.4.2 won't warn you that resolve should be object.

```
resolve: { 
    somekey: function($stateParams, $location){

        //Check if url parameter is missing.
        if ($stateParams.userId === undefined) {
          //Do something such as navigating to a different page.
          $location.path('/somewhere/else');
    }
}
```

If you need minification, [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)

Comment: You are missing an end bracket.