# My state url is matched even if parameter has no value, how do I transition to default state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my UI-Router state:

```js
$stateProvider.state("project",{
  url:'/project/:projectid/:typeid/:directoryid',
  templateUrl: '/app/project/view.html',
  controller: 'projectViewController',
  params:{
    typeid:{squash:true,value:null},
    directoryid:{squash:true,value:null},
  }
});
```

These urls are working fine:

```
/project/5  
/project/5/1  
/project/5/1/2
```

However, this url "/project" is working fine (or being matched), but it should not be.

:projectid should be required. If no value is passed, the url should not match and "otherwise" should switch to default state.

**How do I make it so that projectid is required?**

The "typeid" and "directoryid" parameters should be optional.

Comment: Then make your `project` state an abstract state.

Comment: We use resolve for things like this. Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758274/angularjs-ui-router-mandatory-parameters

Comment: CozyAzure, I made it abstract and that worked. Going with resolve seems like unnecessary if abstract true is what determines if the url matches or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check condition through resolve like as

```
$stateProvider.state("project",{
  url:'/project/:projectid/:typeid/:directoryid',
  templateUrl: '/app/project/view.html',
  controller: 'projectViewController',
  params:{
    typeid:{squash:true,value:null},
    directoryid:{squash:true,value:null},
  },
  resolve: function($stateParams, $location){
    //Check if url parameter is missing.
    if ($stateParams.projectid === undefined) {
      //Do something such as navigating to a different page.
      $location.path('/'); // put any location where you want to redirect
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I see the usefulness of resolve, but abstract true handles it like it should. If you would like to share the differences in benefits that would be great.

Comment: Please go though this link http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/02/angularjs-pitfalls-using-ui-routers-resolve/ hope this clear understanding of uses and      benefits